# file.write only writing 7 bytes of file in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, io

The following code only saves the first 7 bytes to the file correctly and the remaining 3072-7=3065 bytes are incorrect. "correct" meaning the same value as stored in 'data'.

```
#define byte unsigned char
void bytesToImage(byte width, byte height, byte* data, size_t byte_count,  char* fileNameWithoutExtension)
{
    {
        std::ofstream file("k3000", std::ios::binary);
        file.write((char *)data, 3000);
    }
}
```

However this code does save the first 500 bytes correctly:

```
#define byte unsigned char
void bytesToImage(byte width, byte height, byte* data, size_t byte_count, char* fileNameWithoutExtension)
{
    {
        std::ofstream file("k500", std::ios::binary);
        file.write((char *)data, 500);
    }
}
```

`data` has a length of 3072 and the function is called as follows:

```
size_t imageByteCount = 32 * 32 * 3;
byte* imageBufferOut = (byte*)malloc(sizeof(byte) * imageByteCount);
//(imageBufferOut is initialized...)
bytesToImage(32, 32, imageBufferOut, imageByteCount, "img");
```

Please excuse the redundant parameters, I have removed as much as possible to try find the bug.

Hex dumps:
[image]

Comment: Did you try to check the returned value of `fwrite()` ? It must be equal to `byte_count`.

Comment: Include <stdint.h> and typedef uint8_t to declare byte type in c

Comment: " remaining 3072-7=3065 bytes are incorrect. "correct" meaning the same value as stored in 'data'."  What value did you expect? Code does not set the content of `imageBufferOut[]`  It is not initialized and this code does not show how that data was read by you to make the determination of the content.

Comment: @chux sorry, I will clean up and add the initialization code soon, I'm just trying to get the hex dump as requested in the answer below.

Comment: Suspect your initialization code is faulty.  Perhaps overflow with `byte` math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding some more instrumentation.  For example:

```
    {
        cout << "before:";
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
            cout << ' ' << std::hex << int(data[i]);
        cout << '\n';

        std::ofstream file("k3000", std::ios::binary);
        if (file)
            cout << "opened\n";
        else
            cout << "couldn't open\n";
        file.write((char *)data, 3000);
        file.flush();
        if (file)
            cout << "wrote ok\n";
        else
            cout << "write failed\n";

        cout << "after:";
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
            cout << ' ' << std::hex << int(data[i]);
        cout << '\n';
    }
```